# VirtaulMachine Software for development environment?

Tags: virtual-machines

Which virtual machine software is recommended (except virtual box)?

I need it on my mac to run Ubuntu server for development environment?

Wish to share files from server so that I can work on my local machine.

I already tested  VirtualBox but it's not so stable and network setup is broken after every reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of `VirtualBox`, it's free and open-source but you got paid software too like `VMware Fusion` or `Parallels Desktop`.

`Virtualbox` should do the job and of course you need to setup well your network to make it works but it's not because of virtualbox, you'll get the same issue with other virtualization software for sure if your network is not correctly configured.

If the VM is not stable, check if you got `enough CPU/Ram` to host a virtual machine.

Try to adjust your VM ressources to `do not use more than your mac can do`.